# Group R objects into a list

Tags: r

I have loaded a series of SpatialPolygonsDataFrames into my workspace. Each of the named objects has either `"_adm0"`, `"_adm1"`, or `"_adm2"` attached to the country abreviation. For Germany, this would look like `"DEU_adm0"`, `"DEU_adm1"`, and `"DEU_adm2"`.

I'm trying to gather all of the "_adm0" data frames into a list which can then be operated on by ldply and fortify. I could do that with,

`mylist <- list(DEU_adm0, FRA_adm0, RUS_adm0, etc...)` where I write out all of the countries that I want to be included in the list.

But, how do I grab all of the `"_adm0"` data frames by a pattern?

I have started with the code below but it doesn't give me the desired result as writing out

```
adm0list <- ls()[str_detect(ls(), "_adm0")]

mylist   <- sapply(adm0list, function(x) get(x))
```

or alternatively,

```
mylist   <-  mget(adm0list, .GlobalEnv)
```

I do get a list of objects with the `sapply` method, and using `mget()`, but I'm not seeing why those lists are different than using `list()` with the object names directly. I suspect the answer to that question will tell me why `ldply` + `fortify` works with the `list()`method but not the other two.

Comment: `ls` has a pattern argument.

Comment: Thank you Joran, I didn't quite understand you at first, but like Simon's answer below, that solved it.

Comment: Ah, okay, getting the hang of participating on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `pattern` argument of `ls` and then use the `@` extractor for the `data.frame` portion of your `SPDF` objects...

```
#  Construct list of objects wtih mget
ll <- mget( ls( pattern = "_adm0" ) )

#  Extract data.frames
out <- lapply( ll , function(x) x@data )
```

Comment: Simon, that code works, thank you, but my later call of `ldply` + `fortify` on `out` is giving me unexpected results. I'll have to go look at fortify again. I'm left thinking I'm missing a step still. Since throwing all the names manually into list() gives me the `SPDF`s in the right format for fortify.

Comment: @JakeRuss  Yeah if you are using `fortify` it has a method for `SPDF`s so you don't need to exctract the `df` part. You just mentioned it in your op so I put it in, but in this case it's unnecssary. Just use the `mget` call.