# Create a list of data.frames from a vector of data.frame names

Tags: r

I have code to merge many data.frames using the `Reduce`function- but it requires that I manually input the names of the data.frames into a list. I want to create a list and do it on the fly..

Below `patman.summaries` are data.frames (or `tibble`).

```
> patman.summaries
 [1] "KLEC10.summary" "KLEC11.summary" "KLEC12.summary" "KLEC4.summary"  "KLEC5.summary"  "KLEC6.summary"  "KLEC8.summary"  "LEC1.summary"   "LEC2.summary"   "LEC3.summary"  
[11] "LEC7.summary"   "LEC9.summary"
```

However I do not know how to make a list from all of them - my code gives me a list containing only the last `tibble` `LEC9.summary`

```
> list(eval(parse(text = patman.summaries)))
[[1]]
# A tibble: 724 × 2
         mir_name1 LEC9.summary
             <chr>        <int>
1  hsa-let-7a-2-3p            8
2    hsa-let-7a-3p          263
3    hsa-let-7a-5p         1518
4    hsa-let-7b-3p          240
5    hsa-let-7b-5p        10358
6    hsa-let-7c-3p            6
7    hsa-let-7c-5p         1495
8    hsa-let-7d-3p          647
9    hsa-let-7d-5p           77
10   hsa-let-7e-3p           39
# ... with 714 more rows
```

I suppose I can grow this appending within a loop? Is there a direct way please?

Comment: or probably `do.call(rbind, mget(patman.summaries))` in base R.

Comment: @StephenHenderson I based the dupe-ing on the answers : the answers are the same (or very very similar, ie: `do.call(rbind,mget(mats))` and you accepted an answer doing the same, only the `dplyr` way).

Comment: @StephenHenderson would [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19364332/4137985) be better ?

Comment: @akrun I don't close answer, I close questions and I just close duplicate question, it's not my fault if you're keen on answering those

Comment: *" I want to create a list and do it on the fly.."* the answer is `mget` and the question is the same as in this question I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19364332/4137985

Comment: @Cath 1) Don't remove questions because the answer is the same as another. If we knew the answer we wouldn't be asking. 2) Neither the previous question or the new one you just mentioned specify the question similarly so that someone with the same problem would find it... I didn't.

Comment: Seriously, this question could serve as the main example in "What is a duplicate" FAQ. akrun alone has posted [168 answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3732271+mget) using `mget`.  The fact that you couldn't it, doesn't mean it's not a dupe.

Comment: @StephenHenderson The point of marking something a duplicate is that the question stays on the site, and people can use your phrasing of the question as a way to find the correct answer (which is in the duplicate, which is linked). It is not meant to simply delete your question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the values in a `list` and then apply `bind_rows` to get a single data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
mget(patman.summaries) %>% 
                 bind_rows()
```

Comment: `mget(patman.summaries)` is what I want but I'm not using it to `bind_rows`. As the tables are different they need merging. I have code for that and it works now. Thx.

Comment: @StephenHenderson Thanks for the comment, if you need some merging, then `mget(patman.summarises) %>% Reduce(function(...) inner_join(..., by = specifycolumnname), .)`